# MySQL join issue

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to return the results of the products in the product table that were not added by the current user and that the current user has not already reviewed, then sort by the products that have had the least reviews showing those with none first.

- `tblUsers`:

  ```
  UserID
  1
  2
  3
  ```
- `tblProducts`:

  ```
  ProductID UserID (created) NumberReviews
  --------- ---------------- -------------
  1         1                1
  2         1                0
  3         2                1
  4         1                2
  5         2                0
  ```
- `tblReviews`:

  ```
  ReviewID UserID(reviewed) ProductID
  -------- ---------------- ---------
  1        2                4
  2        1                3
  3        3                4
  4        3                1
  ```

So for a current user of 2 I want to return

```
Product ID
----------
2
1
```

I have tried a number of different left joins but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Tip: Add names to each table in your question to make it easier to answer with examples/code.

Comment: Also, you get faster replies if you include some data set-up code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.*
     , COUNT(r.ProductID) AS reviews
FROM tblProducts AS p
  LEFT JOIN tblReviews AS r
    ON r.ProductID = p.ProductID
WHERE UserID <> @currentUser
  AND NOT EXISTS
    ( SELECT *
      FROM tblReviews ru
      WHERE ru.ProductID = p.ProductID
        AND ru.UserID = @currentUser
    ) 
GROUP BY p.ProductID
ORDER BY reviews ASC
```

If you don't want to count but use the field `NumberReviews` for ordering, it's simpler:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM tblProducts AS p
WHERE UserID <> @currentUser
  AND NOT EXISTS
    ( SELECT *
      FROM tblReviews ru
      WHERE ru.ProductID = p.ProductID
        AND ru.UserID = @currentUser
    ) 
ORDER BY NumberReviews ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
SELECT u.*, p.*, r.* FROM users u 
   LEFT JOIN products p ON p.userId <> u.userID 
   LEFT JOIN reviews r ON ( r.productId = p.ProductID AND r.UserID = u.userID)
GROUP BY p.productID ORDER BY p.NumberReviews
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines might work (sql server syntax, not sure about mysql)

```
Select productID 
  from Users u 
    -- all products not created by user
    inner join Products p on p.UserID != u.UserID 
    -- that were reviewed by the user. NOT!
    left outer join Reviews r on p.ProductID = r.ProductID and r.UserID = u.UserID
  where r.ReviewID is null
    and User = CurrentUser
```

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't miss anything:

```
SELECT
  p.ProductID
FROM tblProducts p
  LEFT JOIN tblReviews r ON p.ProductID = r.ProductID AND r.UserID = @UserID
WHERE p.UserID <> @UserID
  AND r.ReviewID IS NULL
ORDER BY p.NumberReviews
```